# How to make a setup cab file using visual studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

The steps given on MSDN for this are:
In Visual Studio 2013, on the File menu, click New, and then click Project.In the New Project dialog box, perform the following steps:Under Project types, expand Other Project Types, and then select Setup and Deployment.Under Templates, select CAB Project.Enter a new Name, Location, and Solution Name for your CAB project and click OK.

But in my Visual Studio 2013 professional I can not find this CAB project in templates.
How to get this?

Answer (score 0):

Install "Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Installer Projects":
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9abe329c-9bba-44a1-be59-0fbf6151054d

It worked for me.